# Node Unzipper Finish called before stream completed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream, unzip, node-streams

I have the following functions which takes in a zip stream, unzips and uploads it to S3:

```
export const unzipAndUpload = async (stream) =>
  stream
    .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
    .on("entry", async entry => {
      await uploadToS3(
        await entry.buffer(),
        entry.path
      );
      console.log("ENTRY", entry.path)
      entry.autodrain();
    })
    .on("finish", () => {
      console.log("FINISH")
    })
    .promise();
```

Currently `FINISH` gets called first and then the `ENTRY` logs continue to print out.

How can I really tell if the stream is really finished? `uploadToS3` requires a buffer so I need to `await` and do certain things synchronously - this is fine. However, how can I be sure all files have been uploaded?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what version of node? I executed this on 12 and I received expected behavior, finished called a the end!

Comment: Oh wow that's interesting. Running 8.7.0. could you try it with that?